# Active Directory testing on Windows XP Home (With Groups, new users, etc)

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am working on a project for a client at home.  I use Windows XP Home edition as my main development (at home).

The client needs some Active Directory projects that require setting up new users, new groups, editing users, etc.  However, I can't seem to get a test environment setup for testing.

I am running VirtualBox and in the past, I had a trial version of Windows Server 2003.  But all I can seem to find now is 2008 and none of the images seem to work with my machine.

Is there a better way for me work with AD?  The project isn't going to pay enough to justify buying 2003/2008.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the problem that you can't run Windows Server 2008 on VirtualBox?

Comment: That's one problem.  The ISO I found for WS2008 said it wouldn't work with my CPU (running in VirtualBox).  I've done it before with WS2003 running under VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to buy anything, the trial virtual machines you can get from Microsoft will work fine.

There is a [trick](http://kwizcom.blogspot.com/2009/11/using-hyperv-vhd-in-sun-virtual-box-no.html) for getting the VMs to work in Virtual Box though. Basically you have to use Virtual PC's VHD wizard utility to compact the HyperV VHD. Then you can create a new VM in Virtual Box using this disk.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that XP home does not offer Active Directory Integration. You need to use XP Pro

Comment: You are correct.  However, the project doesn't pay enough to purchase XP Pro.  Unless I had several of these lined up.

Answer (score 0):

Working with AD, you have a few options:
- Virtual Windows Server Edition (2003/2008/2008R2)
- Linux with Samba Installed (Suse/Fedora - what I usually work with)

It really depends what you mean by 'working with AD' - to be sure, the best (supported) experience is going to be a virtual image with the server.

If you need a separate computer to act as the client, you'll need another virtual image with XP Pro to join to that domain, because home doesn't join a domain (for sure).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if it will work on XP Home, but Microsoft has ADAM, or Active Directory Application Mode, which is sort of a non-server version of AD for applications to use...

The download seems to suggest that Home edition will work.

[ADAM Download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=9688F8B9-1034-4EF6-A3E5-2A2A57B5C8E4&displaylang=en)